# Java method event callback like in C#

Tags: java, events, methods, handler

Hello im doing a tcp server in java, and i got my listener class working but i want to declare an event to the listener class when it is intialized so in the listener class i can call the event newConnection(socket sck) and then it will go over to the main class again and run the method that is binded to that event like you are able to do in C# with the myclass.myevent +=

Can it be done in java or are there other ways arround, i have looked at eventlisteners or what its called but im really confused about how to handle this.

Regards Martin.

Comment: There's no such things as events in core Java - most Java programmers would implement something similar using an Interface callback mechanism

Comment: hmm ok, but do you have some links for it or an explaning about how to do it? :-)

Comment: You want to trigger a custom event somewhere outside a class is that what you wanted.?

Comment: You can also use a PropertyChangeListener or you could go with the observer pattern to pass notifications around. Both concepts have ready to use implementations in Java.

Comment: Yes i want to make the listener class call a method back to the main form :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
public interface ConnectionCallback {

    void onConnected(Socket socket);

}
```

In your listener class:

```
public class Listener {

    public void connect(ConnectionCallback callback){

        //connect to your server here
        Socket socket ....

        callback.onConnected(socket);
    }
}
```

In your main form, or wherever you're creating this listener:

```
public class MainForm{


    public void createListener(){

        Listener listener = new Listener();
        listener.connect(new ConnectionCallback() {
            public void onConnected(Socket socket) {

                 //perform custom logic here on the callback socket

            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Edit: if you were thinking of using Java 8, this might make it slightly easier for you to understand if you're coming from a C# perspective by using lambdas:

```
public class Listener {

    public void connect(Consumer<Socket> socketConsumer){
        Socket socket ....

        socketConsumer.accept(socket);
    }
}
```

Then, your MainForm is simplified:

```
public class MainForm {

    public void createListener(){

        Listener listener = new Listener();
        listener.connect(socket -> onConnected(socket));

    }

    private void onConnected(Socket socket) {
        //perform custom logic here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have tried all day with events and im pretty confused of how to make this work to my main form, so when new connection arrives in listener class it calls a method in form with the socket :-)

Comment: It's difficult to know what you mean by saying you tried with 'events' - what does your current code look like? I've made an edit above to show how you would create an anonymous implementation of the ConnectionCallback interface - think of it as an equivalent of an Action<Socket> in C#.

Comment: I found the solution, i just needed to look a bit at the code :-)

Comment: Ok, well if my answer helped - please mark it as the solution :)

Comment: There seems to be 2 layers of listeners - Listener in turn calls ConnectionCallback. That over-complicates things.

Comment: I agree - though my solution is tailored to the OP's naming convention and original architecture. He just wanted to know how his MainForm can get notified of when a connection is made from his Listener - I'm not going to judge the architecture :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would help:
Declare an interface for your event listener:

```
public interface InitializationListener {
  public void onInitialize();
}
```

Then, in the class which should trigger events:

```
//Using a List allows more than one listener to be registered
private List<InitializationListener> listeners = new ArrayList<InitializationListener>();

public void addInitializationListener(InitializationListener listener) {
  this.listeners.add(listener);
}
```

When you want to trigger the listeners, maybe in newConnection():

```
public void newConnection(Socket sock) {

  //do stuff..

  //trigger listeners:
  for (InitializationListener listener : listeners) {
    listener.onInitialize();
  }

}
```

Finally, in your client code:

```
server.addInitializationListener(new InitializationListener() {

  public void onInitialize() {
     //do stuff
  }

});
```

Comment: yea i think its something like that, its pretty confusing about how to start, but i will try, thanks :)